# Sum edge property and group by the incoming vertice

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have the vertices: `site`, `person`, `interest-category`.
the edges are:

`site->hasUser->person`

`person->hasInterest(count: N)->interest-category` (property `count` saves a number and it's the weight of this interest for this specific user-interest relationship).

Basically I want to get all interests related to a *site* by using its users interests. One example result would be:

```
interest-category: news, totalCount: 15
interest-category: media, totalCount: 20
```

Where totalCount is the sum of edge property `count` for all users of that site/category.

Here's the test sample I'm using:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()

g.addV('person').property(id, 'rodrigo').property('name', 'rodrigo').next()
g.addV('person').property(id, 'john').property('name', 'john').next()
g.addV('site').property(id, 'foxsports').property('name', 'Fox Sports').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'sports').property('name', 'Sports').property('level', 'l1').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'media').property('name', 'Media').property('level', 'l1').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'business-and-finance').property('name', 'Business & Finance').property('level', 'l1').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'soccer').property('name', 'Soccer').property('level', 'l2').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'basketball').property('name', 'Basketball').property('level', 'l2').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'mma').property('name', 'MMA').property('level', 'l2').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'news').property('name', 'News').property('level', 'l2').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'finance').property('name', 'Finance').property('level', 'l2').next()
g.addV('interest-category').property(id, 'sports-industry').property('name', 'Sports Industry').property('level', 'l2').next()


g.addE('hasUser').from(g.V('foxsports')).to(g.V('rodrigo')).next()
g.addE('hasUser').from(g.V('foxsports')).to(g.V('john')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('sports')).to(g.V('soccer')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('sports')).to(g.V('basketball')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('sports')).to(g.V('mma')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('media')).to(g.V('news')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('business-and-finance')).to(g.V('finance')).next()
g.addE('hasSubCategory').from(g.V('business-and-finance')).to(g.V('sports-industry')).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('john')).to(g.V('sports')).property('count', 5).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('sports')).property('count', 5).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('media')).property('count', 3).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('business-and-finance')).property('count', 1).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('soccer')).property('count', 1).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('basketball')).property('count', 1).next()
g.addE('hasInterest').from(g.V('rodrigo')).to(g.V('mma')).property('count', 2).next()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you get from your provided sample graph to this output:

```
interest-category: news, totalCount: 15
interest-category: media, totalCount: 20
```

However, following your plain English description I'd say that you want this query:

```
gremlin> g.V('foxsports').
           out('hasUser').
           outE('hasInterest').
           group().
             by(inV().values('name')).
             by(values('count').sum())
==>[MMA:2,Business & Finance:1,Soccer:1,Media:3,Basketball:1,Sports:10]
```

Reformatted:

```
gremlin> g.V('foxsports').
           out('hasUser').
           outE('hasInterest').
           group().
             by(inV().values('name')).
             by(values('count').sum()).
           unfold().
           project('interest-category','totalCount').
             by(keys).
             by(values)
==>[interest-category:MMA,totalCount:2]
==>[interest-category:Business & Finance,totalCount:1]
==>[interest-category:Soccer,totalCount:1]
==>[interest-category:Media,totalCount:3]
==>[interest-category:Basketball,totalCount:1]
==>[interest-category:Sports,totalCount:10]
```